# Fourier transform is not surjective

Tags: real-analysis

This is exercise 36 p. 270 of Folland's Real Analysis book: Show that the Fourier transform is not surjective from $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ to $C_0(\mathbb{Z})$. He gives a hint saying to note that the result holds on $\mathbb{R}$and if $D_n$ is the Dirichlet kernel we have that the $L^1$ norm of $D_n$ goes to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: What are $T$ and $Z$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez torus and Integers

Comment: Please edit the body of the question to contain all relevant information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the transform is injective, if it were surjective —in view of the open mapping theorem— it would be an isomorphism of Banach spaces, and the corresponding duals would be also isomorphic. But the dual of $L^1$ is $L^\infty$, which is not separable, while the dual of $C_0(\mathbb Z)$ is $\ell_1$, which is.

Actually exhibiting an element which is not in the image takes considerably much more work than the above general-nonsense argument. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3467/274

Comment: This is a cute argument, in that it proves non-surjectivity essentially using an infinitary argument, much as one shows existence of trascendental numbers by counting.