# Prove that trigonometric series is/isn't a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Prove that trigonometric series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nx)}{\ln(n)}$ is a Fourier series and $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\ln(n)}$ is not.

I know a few tricks how to find out whether the trigonometric series are Fourier or not: check its uniform convergence, check the weights convergence to zero; check the Bessel's inequality for the weights.

But these series look so similar - I'm at a loss.

Comment: Both series converge uniformly on every compact subset of $(0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 2):

Theorem 4.2 of "Introduction to Harmonic Analysis" (Y. Katznelson) states that

> Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and assume that $\hat{f}(|n|)=-\hat{f}(-|n|)\geq 0$. Then
>   $$\sum_{n>0}\frac{\hat{f}(n)}{n}<\infty$$

As a corollary, if $a_n>0$ and $\sum_n a_n/n$ is not finite, then the sine series $\sum_{n}a_n\sin nt $ is not a Fourier series.

Comment: The expression $\hat{f}(|n|) = -\hat{f}(|n|)\ge 0$ must contain a typo. Yua are literally saying $\hat{f}(|n|) = 0$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla. Yes of course, thank you.

Comment: @uniquesolution. Thanks, but I don't really understand the theorem. What do you mean by $L^1$? If it's a space of Lebesgue integrable function, i should admit we haven't studied Lebesgue Measure and Integration yet. I hope this 
 could be solved without Lebesgue. Moreover, what does $\hat{f}$ mean? Just some odd function?

Comment: @SliverLight $\hat{f}(n)$ is a standard notation for the $n$'th Fourier coefficient of $f$. In order to define the Fourier coefficient one usually assumes that $f$ is integrable (otherwise it is not clear why the Fourier coefficients exist at all). The notation $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ is a standard notation for the space of Lebesgue integrable functions on the unit circle. Frankly, I am not aware of any other method to prove that your example is not a Fourier series, other than the method presented in the textbook I have made reference to.

Answer (score 1):

This question is fully answered in [example-of-a-trigonometric-series-that-is-not-fourier-series?rq=1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459/example-of-a-trigonometric-series-that-is-not-fourier-series?rq=1). Look at the second answer in that page.

In summary, by the Dirichlet convergence test, the sine series above converges  everywhere and the cosine series converges everywhere except for integer multiples of $2\pi$. [Indeed the Dirichlet convergence test shows that they converge uniformly on any compact set which excludes integer multiples of $2\pi$.] However by the criterion cited above in Katznelson's book (pages 24 & 73), the sine series converges to a function which is not in $L^1$. By definition the constant term coefficient of a Fourier series is the Lebesgue integral
$$c_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(\theta)\ d\theta,$$
which is only defined when $f\in L^1$. Hence the sine series is not a Fourier series. Katznelson (pages 23-24) also shows that the cosine series converges to a function in $L^1$ and that the cosine series is the Fourier series of that function.