# The Fourier series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\log(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Prove that the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\log(n)}$ represented a function $f(x)$ that is not Lebesgue integrable.

My anwser:
Suppose that $f(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\log(n)}$ is Lebesgue integrable. According to  Parseval's theorem, there is integrable function $f$ such that $$\int_{-L}^{L} |f(x)|^{2} dx=2L \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\log^{2} n}.$$ Though, the series is not convergent.

Is my anwser correct?

Comment: You actually proved that the square of function is not Lebesque integrable. To proof that function is not integrable you also need to apply, for example, Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @EugeneSirkiza You meant, $|\int f. f^{-} dx |\leq ||f|| ||f|| $?

Comment: Oh, no. Probably i'm wrong. I think, there is the function that is Lebesgue integrable, but square is not.

Comment: @EugeneSirkiza Indeed, the inclusion is the other way around on a space of finite measure. Consider $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ from $[0,1]$.

Comment: @EugeneSirkiza. My anwser is correct. Because, i assume f is inegrable, so does $f^{2}$ inegrable, on the other hand, i show that it is not square inegrable.

Comment: @MR, good ) now it's fine

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but Parseval gives you a $L^2$ equality, not a $L^1$ one... so your $f$ is not $L^2$, but it says nothing about not being $L^1$, since $L^1$ does not imply $L^2$...

Comment: No, it is the other way around: $x^{-1/2}$ is not $L^2$ but is $L^1$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3467/543769

Comment: @Mindlack You're right. Do you know how can i solve it?

Comment: @Mindlack Whoops, I actually made the same mistake as I corrected the other person on!

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\log n}$$

- Let $$g(x)=\frac{x}{2\pi}- \lfloor \frac{x}{2\pi}\rfloor = \frac12-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n x)}{\pi n}$$ If $f \in L^1(0,2\pi)$ then $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)g(x)dx$ would converge. But $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)g(x)dx =\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)g_k(x)dx= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi n} \frac{1}{\log n} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2(n x) dx= \infty $$

  Where $g_k(x) = g \ast k e^{-\pi k^2 x^2} =\frac12-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n x)}{\pi n} e^{-\pi (2\pi n)^2/k^2}$ is a smooth version of $g$ needed to justify the inversion $\int \sum \sum = \sum\sum \int$.
- Note a partial summation shows that $f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \Im(\sum_{m=2}^n e^{imx}) (\frac{1}{\log n}-\frac{1}{\log n+1})=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\Im(e^{2ix}\frac{1-e^{i(n-1) x}}{1-e^{ix}}) \frac{1/n+O(1/n^2)}{(\log n+1) (\log n)}$ converges and is continuous on $(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: if anyone has a simpler solution...

Comment: The standard proof uses that $U_n(x)=\sum_{1}^{n}{\frac{\sin kx}{k}}$ is pointwise convergent and uniformly bounded in $n,x$, which follows from integrating the dirichlet kernel. Using the above, we can integrate any $g$ in $L^1[0,2\pi]$ against $U_n$ and get the convergence of a series involving the Fourier coefficients of $g$; when $g$ is a sine series, $\sum {a_n \sin nx}$, this convergent series is $\sum {\frac{a_n}{n}}$ and obviously that is not the case here where $a_n= \frac{1}{\log n}$, so basically the above but done directly